# How to show the SVG image in the android imageview

Tags: java, android, svg

I have downloaded the svg-android library from the google code and parsed the SVG image using the SVG parser of svg-android as shown but its displaying nothing.

SVG CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 13.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 14948)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="max_width__x2F__height" display="none">
    <path display="inline" d="M499.001,1v498H1V1H499.001 M500.001,0H0v500h500.001V0L500.001,0z"/>
</g>
<g id="androd">
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M301.314,83.298l20.159-29.272c1.197-1.74,0.899-4.024-0.666-5.104c-1.563-1.074-3.805-0.543-4.993,1.199
        L294.863,80.53c-13.807-5.439-29.139-8.47-45.299-8.47c-16.16,0-31.496,3.028-45.302,8.47l-20.948-30.41
        c-1.201-1.74-3.439-2.273-5.003-1.199c-1.564,1.077-1.861,3.362-0.664,5.104l20.166,29.272
        c-32.063,14.916-54.548,43.26-57.413,76.34h218.316C355.861,126.557,333.375,98.214,301.314,83.298"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M203.956,129.438c-6.673,0-12.08-5.407-12.08-12.079c0-6.671,5.404-12.08,12.08-12.08
        c6.668,0,12.073,5.407,12.073,12.08C216.03,124.03,210.624,129.438,203.956,129.438"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M295.161,129.438c-6.668,0-12.074-5.407-12.074-12.079c0-6.673,5.406-12.08,12.074-12.08
        c6.675,0,12.079,5.409,12.079,12.08C307.24,124.03,301.834,129.438,295.161,129.438"/>
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M126.383,297.598c0,13.45-10.904,24.354-24.355,24.354l0,0c-13.45,0-24.354-10.904-24.354-24.354V199.09
        c0-13.45,10.904-24.354,24.354-24.354l0,0c13.451,0,24.355,10.904,24.355,24.354V297.598z"/>
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M140.396,175.489v177.915c0,10.566,8.566,19.133,19.135,19.133h22.633v54.744
        c0,13.451,10.903,24.354,24.354,24.354c13.451,0,24.355-10.903,24.355-24.354v-54.744h37.371v54.744
        c0,13.451,10.902,24.354,24.354,24.354s24.354-10.903,24.354-24.354v-54.744h22.633c10.569,0,19.137-8.562,19.137-19.133V175.489
        H140.396z"/>
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M372.734,297.598c0,13.45,10.903,24.354,24.354,24.354l0,0c13.45,0,24.354-10.904,24.354-24.354V199.09
        c0-13.45-10.904-24.354-24.354-24.354l0,0c-13.451,0-24.354,10.904-24.354,24.354V297.598z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe you think that you are too loquacious but you are not! Some code, what have you tried etc?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what's wrong with your question. I was just trying to point that your question was inappropriate to get any helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this [svg-android lib](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) (and I think so), then you can see that there are some [tutorials](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial).

In short, you should do in this case something like this:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create a new ImageView
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        // Set the background color to white
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // Parse the SVG file from the resource
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
        // Get a drawable from the parsed SVG and set it as the drawable for the ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        // Set the ImageView as the content view for the Activity
        setContentView(imageView);
    }
```

If you saw this, and do the same, then there may be problems with your SVG. Did you try to open it somewhere else? Or better paste here source of your SVG, please

Comment: Yes I have used the same SVG parser code and download the svg image from there itself.
Is there any library dependencies..?

Comment: Seems that I can't help you. Please, check that dependencies of SVGParser are correct, svg image placed to res/raw folder. Also you can try to set flag "android:hardwareAccelerated=false" to AndroidManifest.xml in <application> tag (for my phone there was this exception when I tried to run code: https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=303). I can say, that I tested this piece of code with the same svg on Android 4.0.3 and everything is working like a charm