# Download and display svg image in Android

Tags: android, svg, download, imageview, picasso

I am trying to download and display an svg image in my ImageView. I am using Picasso to display my other images from the web. However, now I have to show the svg images and I cannot get to decode the image.

This is how I do he rest of the images :-

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(mProject.getAvatar())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_description_blue_grey_600_36dp)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_description_blue_grey_600_36dp)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

How can I display SVG images from the web? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the SVG image in the android imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055896/how-to-show-the-svg-image-in-the-android-imageview)

Comment: Possible duplicate, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable)

Comment: @VikashParajuli I need to download the image from web and then display it to the imageview. The question shows how to display the image which I stored in resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this library 
[AndroidSvgLoader](https://github.com/ar-android/AndroidSvgLoader)

Comment: I tried this. It gives me an error while adding it to the gradle saying `Error:(52, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.1`

Comment: add this line in your projects build.gradle- it is clearly mentioned on their github page how to use this lib                         
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

Comment: I have added that as well

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file. its working fine just now i build.

Comment: Thanks. There was some issue while adding it to the gradle.